# A way to add data "mid stream" to encoded audio (possibly with AAC)

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, codec, aac

Is there a way to add lossless data to an AAC audio stream?

Essentially I am looking to be able to inject "this frame of audio should be played at XXX time" every n frames in.

If I use a lossless codec I suppose I could just inject my own header mid stream and that data would be intact as it needs to be the same on the way out just like gzip does not loose data.

Any ideas?  I suppose I could encode the data into chunks of AAC on the server and on the network layer add a timestamp saying play the following chunk of AAC at time x but I'd prefer to figure a way to add it to the audio itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible (short of writing your own specialized encoder), as AAC (and MP3) frames are not truly standalone.

There is a concept of the bit reservoir, where unused bandwidth from one frame can be utilized for a later frame that may need more bandwidth to store a more complicated sound.  That is, data from frame 1 might be needed in frame 2 and/or 3.  If you cut the stream between frames 1 and 2 and insert your alternative frames, the reference to the bit reservoir data is broken and you have damaged frame 2's ability to be decoded.

There are encoders that can work in a mode where the bit reservoir isn't used (at the cost of quality).  If operating in this mode, you should be able to cut the stream more freely along frame boundaries.

Unfortunately, the best way to handle this is to do it in the time domain when dealing with your raw PCM samples.  This gives you more control over the timing placement anyway, and ensures that your stream can also be used with other codecs.